# How Can I Put Escape Character before Special Characters using C#?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, vb.net, winforms

```
buildLetter.Append("</head>").AppendLine();
buildLetter.Append("").AppendLine();
buildLetter.Append("<style type="text/css">").AppendLine();
```

Assume the above contents resides in a file. I want to write a snippet that
removes any line which has empty string "" and put escape character before
the middle quotations. The final output would be:

```
buildLetter.Append("</head>").AppendLine();
buildLetter.Append("<style type=\"text/css\">").AppendLine();
```

The outer " .... " is not considered special chars. The special chars may be single
quotation or double quotation.

I could run it via find and replace feature of Visual Studio. However, in my case i
want it to be written in c# or VB.NET

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: How do you know which quote marks end the string and which should be escaped? Could you have something like `("a" + "b")`, and if so should this be changed to `("a\" + \"b")`?

Comment: Both of them should be escaped. A rule of thumb, the first and last quote must not be escaped. Any other quotes have to be escaped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps this does what you want:

```
string s = File.ReadAllText("input.txt");
string empty = "buildLetter.Append(\"\").AppendLine();" + Environment.NewLine;
s = s.Replace(empty, "");
s = Regex.Replace(s, @"(?<="").*(?="")",
         match => { return match.Value.Replace("\"",  "\\\""); }
    );
```

Result:

```
buildLetter.Append("</head>").AppendLine();
buildLetter.Append("<style type=\"text/css\">").AppendLine();
```